# How to show the "modern" open file dialog?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm remaking on Visual Studio (on C# WPF application mode) an application made on AutoPlay media Studio.

When I needed get files from computer, I found on StackOverflow and in other sites a code to do it, using OpenFileDialog(); but this code shows the older dialog:

[image]

But, on the Application made in AMS, the "Open File" is the "Modern" Dialog Window.

Is there any way to Show the "modern" Open File dialog on C# WPF?

Comment: When I made this post, I didn't have enough reputation.

Comment: Are you using `System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog` or `Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog`? Btw both work the same on my machine, but I have Windows 7 (your screenshot looks like Vista).

Comment: Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog

Comment: Yes, I have Windows 7.

Comment: possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/a/3885370/361100

Comment: For me, it turned out that having `.ShowHelp = true` in `OpenFileDialog` in a .NET 4.8 project was the problem. When `ShowHelp = true` WinForms will show the old version for some reason. Setting `ShowHelp = false` caused the new version to appear. Yet another WinForms gotcha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks vesan, I changed Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog to System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog, and now the code shows the "Modern" Open File Dialog!

Now I just have to adjust the code to work completely.

Comment: Not sure why, but both versions of `OpenFileDialog` have the exact same "modern" appearance on my machine (tested .NET Framework 4 & 4.5, Win 7 Enterprise 64bit)

Comment: My project uses .NET Framework 3.5, and my SO is Win 7 Ultimate 64-bit. '-'

Comment: Based on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3885245/how-to-open-new-openfiledialog-automatically-in-vista-win7/3885370#3885370) that **Youngjae** linked in the comments, then your problem must have lied in .NET 3.5: _"Yes, you'd have to upgrade to .NET 4.0 to get the new dialog. If you're stuck on 3.5 then you can use System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog"_. Good to know :)

Answer (score -1):

OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();

```
dlg.Filter = "All Media Files|*.wav;*.aac;*.wma;*.wmv;*.avi;*.mpg;*.mpeg;*.m1v;*.mp2;*.mp3;*.mpa;*.mpe;*.m3u;*.mp4;*.mov;*.3g2;*.3gp2;*.3gp;*.3gpp;*.m4a;*.cda;*.aif;*.aifc;*.aiff;*.mid;*.midi;*.rmi;*.mkv;*.WAV;*.AAC;*.WMA;*.WMV;*.AVI;*.MPG;*.MPEG;*.M1V;*.MP2;*.MP3;*.MPA;*.MPE;*.M3U;*.MP4;*.MOV;*.3G2;*.3GP2;*.3GP;*.3GPP;*.M4A;*.CDA;*.AIF;*.AIFC;*.AIFF;*.MID;*.MIDI;*.RMI;*.MKV";

dlg.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: The question is not about to show "any" dialog, but the "modern" dialog. This seems to be answered in the already given answer.