# Dark mode discrepancy in file dialogs in Windows Forms (.NET)

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, darkmode

Writing an application in C#/.NET (Windows Forms/.NET Framework 4.7.2)

When I invoke a `SaveFileDialog` form within my application, it seems to honor the system's settings (a light dialog shows when dark mode is disabled globally, a dark dialog shows when dark mode is enabled system-wide).

Within the same application, the `OpenFileDialog` and `FolderBrowserDialog` are always shown in "light mode", regardless of the system settings.

Is there a way to force `OpenFileDialog` and `FolderBrowserDialog` to honor the system's theme?

**EDIT 1:**
It seems that the `SaveFileDialog` control invokes the system's native `Save Dialog`, whereas the `OpenFileDialog` (and possibly the `FolderBrowserDialog`) controls in .NET are wrappers over the native system dialogs. In that regard, an acceptable "workaround" would be to invoke the native dialogs from within .NET (possibly using Windows API), assuming that the native dialogs would honor the system's dark mode settings by default.

**EDIT 2:**
Regarding `OpenFileDialog`, and after coming across [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29596816/how-to-show-the-modern-open-file-dialog) where one of the comments suggested that having `ShowHelp` enabled was causing an "older" dialog version to be displayed, I managed to get the "modern" dialog to show. Although I did not have `ShowHelp` enabled myself, I did have `ShowReadOnly` enabled. Disabling it did the trick. Not sure if this behavior is documented but it sure isn't obvious. As far as this question is concerned, while the `OpenFileDialog` issue is now resolved, the `FolderBrowserDialog` one remains.

Comment: What version of .net do you use?

Comment: @NineBerry .NET Framework 4.7.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the `OpenFileDialog` to support Dark Mode, make sure its `AutoUpgradeEnabled` property is set to True. Also make sure its `ShowReadOnly` and `ShowHelp` properties are set to false. The modern dialog variant doesn't support these ui elements.

The `FolderBrowserDialog` also has an `AutoUpgradeEnabled` that allows it to support Dark Mode, but only starting with .net Core. This is not supported in .Net Framework up to 4.8.

As long as you remain with .net Framekwork 4.x, replace the `FolderBrowserDialog` with some other component. There are a ton open source variants of the FolderBrowserDialog or variants of `OpenFileDialog` with support for only selecting folders out there.

You can also write your own variant of the `OpenFileDialog` that supports only picking folders based on the [`IFileDialog` API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-ifiledialog). Set the [`FOS_PICKFOLDERS` option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/ne-shobjidl_core-_fileopendialogoptions#constants). See for example [Trying to open a file dialog using the new IFileDialog and IFileOpenDialog interfaces in C# with minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4136477/trying-to-open-a-file-dialog-using-the-new-ifiledialog-and-ifileopendialog-inter) or [Show detailed Folder Browser from a PropertyGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15386992/101087) for possible implementations.